# apache secure https redirect to non-secure page

Tags: apache, redirect

how can I redirect request for SSL secured page https://www.mysite.com  to non-secure http://www.mysite.com

I tried this, but it did not work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I did a phpinfo() and see  mod_rewrite under Configuration >> apache2handler >> loaded modules section.

Answer (score 0):

Add R (redirect) flag to RewriteRule as follows:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

Redirect is done by HTTP status 301 by default.  If you want to redirect by specific status code, e.g. "301 Moved Permanently", you can specify any valid redirect status code (3xx):

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Check [document (Apache Module mod_rewrite)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for detail.